# Can I use phoenix to achieve the feature like SQL's duplicate key?

Tags: apache-phoenix

I want to use phoenix to insert data into Hbase like this:

```sql
INSERT INTO mytable (col1, col2) VALUES (?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE col2 = col2 + ?
```

Is there any method to achieve this in phoenix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just an update, the feature has been released with [Phoenix 4.9](https://blogs.apache.org/phoenix/entry/announcing_phoenix_4_9_released), the syntax being:

```sql
UPSERT INTO mytable (col1, col2) VALUES (?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE col2 = col2 + ?;
UPSERT INTO mytable (col1, col2) VALUES (?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY IGNORE;
```

Answer (score 0):

No. It's not yet available. See related JIRA for some initial discussion to support above usecase.
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PHOENIX-6